# Icons, toolbars, checkboxes and dialog windows are the wrong size in VMware guest OS

Tags: windows-server-2016, vmware-workstation

When running Windows Server 2016 in VMware workstation, I've found that for some programs the icons, toolbars, checkboxes and dialog windows are far smaller than they should be when accessing the guest via the VMware Workstation console. If I RDP onto the server then the icons, toolbars, checkboxes and dialog windows are sized correctly.

Most of the time this is just an annoyance but with some programs the dialog windows are being badly resized to the point they are unusable (see last screenshot) and its not always practical to RDP onto the guest OS. The problem only seems to affect a very small number programs, and in the vast majority of cases the icons, toolbars, checkboxes and dialog windows are sized appropriate. The problem seems to affect dialog windows that are part of the OS such as the network adapter settings, and other Microsoft applications such as FsLogix.

I'm running Windows 10 (version 1909) on the host, VMware Workstation 15.5, and Windows Server 2016 (version 1607) as the guest OS with VMware tools version 11.5.1. I've played with the various display settings in VMware workstation (fullscreen, stretch guest window, autosize etc) but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Any ideas what might be causing the issue or how I can troubleshoot this further?

Here are some screenshots of various windows.
[image: Network Adapter Settings - Checkboxes Tiny]

[image: FsLogix - Toolbar icons tiny]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using a high-dpi monitor and Windows set the scaling factor something greather than 100%.

Open Settings -> System -> Display -> Scale and Layout -> set to 100%